# Observer not firing after checkout

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have created an observer but it does not seem to ever fire - I need to replicate `sales_order_place_after` from an old Magento 1.9.X module into the one I am refactoring for Magento2

So far I have `\MyVendor\Order\etc\events.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="MyObserver" instance="MyVendor\Order\Observer\OrderObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And also `OrderObserver.php` which is:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\Order\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::_construct();
        //Observer initialization code...
        //You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //Observer execution code...
        $this->logger->debug('Order Observer');
    }
}
```

I've tried moving the events.xml into a sub folder of etc for frontend, but I seem unable to reach my debug log. What have I done that needs amending to get this observer to fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks Like you messed up with directory structure that's why its not working for you.

Below is tested with Magento Instance.

> MyVendor\Order\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="MyObserver" instance="MyVendor\Order\Observer\OrderObserver" />
</event>
</condfig>
```

> MyVendor\Order\Observer\OrderObserver.php

```
namespace MyVendor\Order\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(Observer $observer)
  {
      echo "Observer Executed"; exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi - I did say that I had tried it in a subfolder for frontend but that also did not work. Otherwise I cannot see a difference in your structure to mine.

Comment: I used same code, As I posted above its working for me. Please verify that you have created necessary files for basic module.

Comment: Yes there is a module in place, and other aspects of the module are working.

Comment: Can't help with that, Its working for me as above code.

Comment: Even if you log rather than echo and exit?

Comment: @Aravona, Yes, If i cerate log it also working for me. Why dont you give a try to my code ? Hope it worth it.!!

Comment: Got it working :)